# Two $firebaseArrays on one page & one ctrl

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I would like to use two different $firebaseArrays on one view with one controller. But only one of them works and the other only works if i put him in his own controller.

from my factory file:

```
.factory("AlphaFactory", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('alpha/');
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
])

.factory("BetaFactory", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('beta/');
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
])
```

and my controller:

```
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, AlphaFactory, BetaFactory) {
  $scope.alphaJobs = AlphaFactory;
  $scope.addalphaJob = function() {
    $scope.alphaJobs.$add({
      Testentry: $scope.loremipsum,
      timestamp: Date()
    });

    $scope.alphaJob = "";
  };

  $scope.betaJobs = BetaFactory;
  $scope.addbetaJob = function() {
    $scope.betaJobs.$add({
      Testentry2: $scope.dolorest,
      timestamp: Date()
   });

   $scope.betaJob = "";
  };
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not a simple matter of a promise has not finished?

```
var alphaJobs = AlphaFactory;
alphaJobs.$loaded().then(function() {
    // Do something with data if needed

   $scope.alphaJobs = alphaJobs;
});

var betaJobs = BetaFactory;
betaJobs.$loaded().then(function() {
    // Do something with data if needed

   $scope.betaJobs = betaJobs;
});
```

Comment: thank your for your suggestion, but still no luck. i see that it connects to the firebase (a select field gets populated) but still not able to save to firebase. by the way, i get this warning via the console: [link]https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832

Comment: Link is broken. The Chrome status though is for your code, not the link in with Firebase or the processing of the two factories. The two factories then depend on what you are doing.  As these have been added to the $scope, any changes from your page should then be reflected in the database provided your references are valid.